# Session variable not displaying

Tags: php, session, variables

So I create a session on one page and create a new variable called uName and assign a value.
I go to another page and try to echo the value but I get an error:"Undefined variable _SESSION"

here is the code:

The page where I start the session and create the variable uName

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['uName'] = "Mike";
?>
```

The page where I try to echo the variable's value:

```
<?php echo "My Name is " . $_SESSION['uName'];?>
```

There is nothing else in my code except for a shell of a page just html, head, title, body and paragraph tags, all properly nested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call session_start() again at beginning of the new file, like so:

```
<?php 
session_start();

echo "My Name is " . $_SESSION['uName'];
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that you has to start the session on each page to resume the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add session_start(); to all files that use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['uName'] = "Mike";
?>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "My Name is " . $_SESSION['uName'];
//eventually
unset($_SESSION['uName']);
?>
```