# php: how to shoow session variable on every php page

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Session variable not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270155/session-variable-not-displaying)

This is the code on index.php where i get session variable first time:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['text'];
$sesvar = $_SESSION['User'];
```

when I go to another php page of same website and again come back to index.php session automatically get destroyed.I want session until user dont logout it.

For that I passed parameter of session variable again to index page and wrote the following code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['User']))
{
  $sesvar = $_GET['sid']; 
  session_start();
  //echo $sesvar;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Using `session_start();` on each page where you want to use the session is sufficient.

You can then use `$_SESSION['User']` to access the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this on every page you will be overwriting the contents of $_SESSION['User'] when nothing is in the $_POST['text'];

You should try something like:

```
if(!empty$_POST['text'])){
    $_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['text'];
}
```